# JsonReader and android 2.3.3

Tags: java, android

I am building my application for android level 10 (version 2.3.3).

I need to use JsonReader, but it does not exist in this version, nor does it seem to be in the support packages.

Can anyone tell me if there is a workaround - other than compiling to level 11 of course ?

Answer (score 1):

I had added some files from android source to my project - these cources are written without hidden API

[StringPool](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/libcore/internal/StringPool.java)

JsonReader.java

JsonScope.java

JsonToken.java

from any source hub.

Answer (score 0):

You can find any open source library(in jar format) and added it in the classpath.

You can read it in details in this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668862/good-json-java-library)

Or you can create your own utility class by using some java class that available in http://www.json.org/java/